# Program Terminates unexpectedly C++

Tags: c++, eclipse, pointers, queue

The goal of the program is to simulate a medical complex with 6 "Doctor Queues". I tried keeping it close enough to the Java version I've completed (must do this in 3 languages). At this point when I run the `DequeuePatients` and `ListPatients` method, the program terminates unexpectedly with no errors. I've tried the debugger but eclipse is ignoring all my breakpoints.Why is it terminating?

The ListPatients method is all follows in Driver class:

```
void ListPatients() {

    int x, QueueChoice = 0;
    bool exit = false;``

    while (!exit) {
        for (x = 1; x <= MAX; x++) {
            cout << x << ": " << Doctor[x - 1] << "\n";
        } // end-for

        cout << "Choose a Queue to List From";
        cin >> QueueChoice;

        if (OpenFlag[QueueChoice - 1] == true) { //open flag for each queue
        int i = Complex[QueueChoice - 1]->GetSize();//Global array of queues
        //cout <<i<<endl;
```

1. Terminates in this loop if function is called

   ```
    for (x = 1; x <= i; x++) {
           Patient This = Complex[QueueChoice-1]->GetInfo(x); //Program Terminates here
           cout << x<< ": " << endl;//This.ID_Number;
              //<<Complex[QueueChoice - 1]->GetInfo(x + 1).PrintMe()
       } // end-for
   } // end-if

   cout << "Press 1 to List Another Queue, press 2 to exit";
   cin >> x;
   switch (x) {
   case 1:
       break;
   case 2:
       exit = true;
       break;
     }//switch
    } // end-while
   } // List Patients`
   ```

Queue Class GetInfo and toArray():

```
/*Return Patient info from each Node*/
Patient Queue::GetInfo(int Pos) {
    Node* ComplexArray= new Node[Length];
     ComplexArray = this->toArray();
    return ComplexArray[Pos - 1].Info;
}

// The toArray method
Node* Queue::toArray() {
    // Copy the information in each node to an array and return the array.
    int x = Length;
    Node ComplexArray[Length] ={} ;
    Node* Current = new Node();
    Current = Rear;`
    for (x = 0; x<Length;x++) {
        ComplexArray[x] = Node();
        ComplexArray[x].Modify(Current);
        Current = Current->Next;
    }
    return ComplexArray;
} // End of toArray method
```

Modify Method in Node:

```
 void Node :: Modify(Node* ThisNode)
 {
     Info = ThisNode->Info;
     Next = ThisNode->Next;
 }
```

Comment: What is `Complex` and what does `GetInfo` do? What happens if you run it through in a debugger?

Comment: QueueChoice is not going to be equal to the number as you type it in

Comment: Complex is an array of 6 Queue class objects, all containing Nodes. Each Node contains a Patient `Info` object and a pointer to the next Node. GetInfo should return the Patient object contained in each Node.

Comment: `GetInfo` calls `toArray` which has `x=0` and sets `ComplexArray[x-1]` which will be `0-1` to start with.

Comment: It's been updated, 'error' persists

Comment: must've lost track of some of the things I was doing to find a correction

Comment: ... version control is rather helpful for that sort of thing

Answer (score 2):

If this is base-zero why are you subtracting 1 from `x`

```
for (x = 0; x<Length;x++) {
    ComplexArray[x-1] = Node();
    ComplexArray[x - 1].Modify(Current);
    Current = Current->Next;
}
```

Subscript errors are hard crashes in C/C++.

Comment: *Subscript errors are hard crashes in C/C++.* Really?

Comment: 5 a.m. tunnel vision I suppose, It has been corrected. Error still persists

Answer (score 0):

The problem was sort of basic, it was way I was declaring my pointers, as well as changing the `toArray` function to return a Patient pointer(That can be treated as an array?) as apposed to Node, and not just to the first element of the array.

this  caused toArray to return one Node pointer, with that instances `Next` pointer continuously pointing to itself.

`Queue Complex[6] = Queue(); //in driver class
Patient* ComplexArray[Length] = new Patient();//Queue Class GetInfo & toArray`

I needed:

`Queue* Complex = new Queue[MAX];
Patient* ComplexArray = new Patient[Length];`

and changed these functions:

```
Patient Queue::GetInfo(int Pos) {
    Patient* ComplexArray = new Patient[Length];
    ComplexArray= toArray();

    return ComplexArray[Pos - 1];
}

// Now returns Patient pointer of Node->Info to GetInfo
Patient* Queue::toArray() {
    Node* Current;
    int x;
    Patient* ComplexArray =  new Patient[Length];
    Current = Rear;
    for (x = 1; x <= Length; x++) {
        ComplexArray[x-1] = Patient();
        ComplexArray[x - 1].Modify(Current->Info);
        Current = Current->Next;
    }
    return ComplexArray;
} // End of toArray method
```